# Why 169.254.0.0 appears by default in the routing table?

Tags: networking, ethernet, static-ip

I defined a subnet on `eth0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` with:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback  

auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet static  
        address 192.168.1.1  
        netmask 255.255.255.0  
        network 192.168.1.0
```

This subnet will be used to communicate to a Raspberry Pi connected on my ethernet port. Internet connection is not needed because already provided by wifi.

I was expecting my laptop to get the static ip address 192.168.1.1 when I run `sudo ifup eth0` and it's the case. However, `route -n` shows:

```
Kernel IP routing table  
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  
... (bunch of things) ...  
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

1. Why do I have a 169.254.0.0 line?
2. I believe it's unnecessary. How do I remove it?

Comment: Related http://serverfault.com/q/132657

Comment: Agreed, but I don't have the /etc/sysconfig folder on Ubuntu. Would you know what is the equivalent?

Comment: "**However**, route -n shows:..." Are you sure your `route -n` output didn't have this before you activated `eth0`?

Comment: Yes. If I do "sudo ifdown eth0" there is nothing relating to eth0 in the "route -n" output. Then if I do a "sudo ifup eth0", I have the two lines I mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the quoted link:

> If a DHCP client attempts to get an address, but fails to find a DHCP
>   server after the timeout and retries period it will randomly assume an
>   address from this network. This allows communication with hosts that
>   have failed to obtain a DHCP address.

However, your *interfaces* file requests a static IP address that is likely impossible, so no valid address was given.

192.168.1.1 is likely the address of the router or other access point to which you are attempting to connect. Therefore, the address will not be granted. Moreover, if you expect to connect to the internet, you will need to specify DNS nameservers. May I suggest:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Of course verify the exact details before you proceed.

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: The king of networking questions is back :)

Comment: Thanks! I am not looking to connect to the internet through this ethernet connection, this is already done through wifi. I want to use the subnet to communicate via ssh with my raspberry Pi. I'll edit the question!

Comment: Is this also so you can share the internet with the Pi? Is wireless managed by Network Manager or by the *interfaces* file? If the latter, may we see the entire file?

Comment: If internet could be shared with the Pi that would be AMAZING. But I have not been successfull yet.

Wifi is managed by network manager. What you saw was the whole /etc/network/interfaces file, there nothing more in it.

Comment: I'm certain it can be done, but it is both beyond the scope of this question and beyond my limited knowledge. I am not sure it can be done, however, partly in NM and partly in *interfaces*.  I recommend you start a new question referencing "internet connection sharing to Pi."

Comment: @Shinagan: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: What about the `169.254.0.0`?

Comment: @detly exactly...neither of the 2 questions were actually answered

Comment: @chili555 On my system today ([problems just started after years](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312745/suddenly-ethernet-wifi-wont-co-exist)) only Ethernet has 169.254.00 and WiFi does not when using `netstat -rn` is that normal?

Answer (score 3):

Per [RFC 3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) (emphasis mine):

> To participate in wide-area IP networking, a host needs to be
> configured with IP addresses for its interfaces, either manually by
> the user or automatically from a source on the network such as a
> Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) server.  Unfortunately,
> such address configuration information may not always be available.
> It is therefore beneficial for a host to be able to depend on a
> useful subset of IP networking functions even when no address
> configuration is available.  **This document describes how a host may
>
> automatically configure an interface with an IPv4 address within the
> 169.254/16 prefix that is valid for communication with other devices    connected to the same physical (or logical) link.**

So, to summarize, the 169.254/16 subnet was reserved to allow for communications between two physically (or logically, e.g. through a switch) connected devices without having to rely on DHCP or manual assignment of static IP addresses.

To quote the [Wikipedia article on private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network),

> If a host on an IEEE 802 (Ethernet) network cannot obtain a network
> address via DHCP, an address from 169.254.1.0 to 169.254.254.255 may
> be assigned pseudorandomly.

As an example of its usage, say you have two embedded devices that need to communicate with one another via a direct Ethernet connection, but you want one or both devices to first look for DHCP so they also have the possibility of being connected into a local area network. When the devices are connected directly together and there is no DHCP available, the devices may use a protocol such as [multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) to discover each other automatically, but each device must first have some arbitrary IP address assigned so they can actually talk to each other over the Ethernet link. Thus, the operating system automatically assigns an IP address to the Ethernet device from the 169.254/16 network.

---

Now, as for why that route is there in the routing table by default...if you look at `/etc/networks`, you can see that the 'link-local' network is defined as being in this subnet:

```
$ cat /etc/networks
# symbolic names for networks, see networks(5) for more information
link-local 169.254.0.0
```

If you take this file's advice and check out `man networks`, you'll see:

> This file is read by the route(8) and netstat(8) utilities.

So the route is created automatically on boot after `route` reads that file.

---

The route is only necessary if you plan to actually use link-local communications and don't want to assign a static IP address to the connected devices. But it doesn't do any harm to leave it in if you don't.

However, if you *really* want to remove it, you can do so with

```
sudo route del -net 169.254.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0
```

Or to remove it permanently, you should be able to just comment out its entry in `/etc/networks` and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `169.254.0.0` is present in your routing table because `ifup` is setting up the `link-local` network.

To avoid this, consider using `ifconfig` instead of `ifup`.

If necessary, run `ifdown` first.

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1
```

`ifconfig` does less work and does not read `/etc/network/interfaces`.

It should be possible to share internet access with the Pi.  You need to turn on packet forwarding in the kernel on your laptop.  I think this can be done without rebooting.  I have done it in the past, but do not know how to do it off the top of my heard.  This might help:

[How do I bridge network interfaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62027/how-do-i-bridge-network-interfaces)