# Ubuntu server network switch

Tags: networking, server, samba

I tried just a regular bridge, but the same issue no router setting access "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" and no samba share from my server. Then I try to setup netplan whit dhcp and static IP same deal "https://www.tecmint.com/create-network-bridge-in-ubuntu/"
and I even pull-out my unraid network config file to see how it was config, and I setup everything up as I didn't in unraid.

[image: my network setup]

My server and my pc have access to ethernet I can watch video and so on but if I want to access my samba share I need to enter manually the IP a location in Windows otherwise Windows doesn't see it

---

After installing Ubuntu on my gaming pc everything worked. I can connect to my Samba share and access my router settings. I don't know why it's blocked in Windows.

I installed wsdd, and now I have the share in the network tab, but I still don't have access to my router. however, I made a hyper-v with network in bridge mode, and I have access to everything. I just don't get it; wth is my PC not able to access my router? Yes I disable the firewall and the same thing.

[image: here is a screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I bridge network interfaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62027/how-do-i-bridge-network-interfaces)

Comment: You want a *bridge*. You do *not* want to *share internet connection* - which is really NATing.

Comment: Vidarlo can you help me because I try making a bridge whit dhcp for ipv4 but my server was connected to internet but not my pc

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fixed now after installing wsdd and changing the dns in my router to 1.1.1.1 & 1.0.0.1. Now I have access to my Samba share and my router settings. I don't know why and how, but it works now. I bought a 10GB switch anyway, so at least I will have network redundancy on my server in case a cable or a connector broke.